# IIS site setup with a different port

Tags: iis, iis-7

We are having a situation where we have to create use the site with different ports

1) 80 goes to site -xyz

2) 1443 goes to some other site - abc.zyx which uses same root folder.

SO we have added 1443 to iis server bindings along with a new private ip. This site as of now uses same root folder as the root site with port as 80.

Now the privateip:port is not coming up. Need to view the same site with port 1443.

Kindly help

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you are asking but you can create two separate sites in IIS to look at the same root folder as long as they have different host names.

The same can be said about ports. You can add multiple ports in the sites bindings as long as they are actually different ports.

Just make sure all ports are open on the firewalls. You should be OK.